# Can we use drupal AHAH in webform module of drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform, ahah

I intend to add dynamically fields like text boxes, radio buttons, checkboxes ,select boxes on a click of button like "ADD More".

I heard we can use AHAH to add fields dynamically, since I used a webform module to build my form, can I still be able to use AHAH to add the feature of "dynamically addition of fields" ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution, Simply used php files in building web pages and got the required functionality.
Simple web pages will have an option to add php scripts directly. And relying on AHAH is No- No for the required functionality.